# Mission Impossible: get from Sunnyvale to the Google campus

Tags: routes, silicon-valley, commute

I need to get from Sunnyvale (82/Lawrence Expy) to the Google Campus (Garcia Ave) in Mountain View. Never been there before.

I have been warned not to take 85 as it is supposedly totally gridlocked during rush hour.

What is the best strategy? Some of the possibilities:

- LawrenceExpy to 101
- 82 to North Rengstorff
- Central Expressway to North Rengstorff
- Middlefield Road to North Rengstorff

Any advice as to the best route?

Comment: I would personally just install [Waze](http://www.waze.com), owned by Google incidentally, and drive wherever it tells you. You'll get the best route available based on realtime traffic for the time that you're driving and can compare the route options as you wish. Plus you'll get a time estimate so you know when to leave.

Comment: @ZachLipton I don't use cell phones.

Comment: I can use Waze for you if you tell me the time of day for the trip.

Comment: So firstly, 82/Lawrence is in Santa Clara, not Sunnyvale.  Secondly, how are you planning to travel?  Walking?  Bus? Car?  Plane?  Personal Jet Pack?  Teleportation?

Comment: @Doc By car. Do people walk on 101?

Comment: On you going to be on your own in the car? The 101 has an HOV lane there for 2 or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're starting right by El Camino (CA-82) and the Lawrence Expressway, Google Maps and Waze [generally recommend](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/37.3501515,-121.9955315/1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA/@37.3543024,-122.0013331,15.62z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fba027820e5d9:0x60a90600ff6e7e6e!2m2!1d-122.0843491!2d37.4224187) the Lawrence Expressway to 101. This is the most logical and direct route as well and is probably, on average marginally faster than the Central Expressway. Waze estimates at least 25 minutes for this trip during the morning commute, which can extend past 10:00am.

Even without a smartphone, you could still check Google Maps before you leave for up-to-date traffic information that might cause you to choose another route.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the intersection of El Camino Real (82) and Lawrence is in Santa Clara, not Sunnyvale - but near enough.

There is no correct answer to this question.

I live very (very!) close to the intersection of El Camino (82) and Lawrence.  I do part or all of the drive you're referring to frequently.  The best route will depend on the day of the week and the time of day.

For someone that doesn't know the area, the best option will almost certainly be Lawrence to 101, and then 101 to Google. At most this will take 5-10 minutes longer than any other route, and the odds of you getting lost are significantly lower than on the other routes.

For someone that knows the area, and know what the traffic is like on the particular day, better options may include Lawrence/Central Expressway/85/101, Central Expressway/Rengstorff, 82/85/101 or even 82/Fremont/85/101.

Despite what you've been told, 85 is no worse than any other road.  In fact, any back-up on 85 is caused by backup on 101 where the two merge.

I've driven every one of the routes above and more countless times - the one thing that this drive isn't is a Mission Impossibleas your subject implies...